# Client running on browser cannot access the API inside the same docker-compose container

Tags: reactjs, docker, testing, docker-compose, cypress

I have a docker-compose container with client, api server, and cypress. Once I run the cypress test inside the container, it's able to open up the browser and access the client. But once the client is making an API call to the server it fails and return "Network request failed". The API URL I used in the client is "http://server:8888", also these three containers are in the same docker-compose network.

Command I use to run cypress tests: "docker-compose run cypress npx cypress run --config baseUrl=http://client:8080 --headless"

What might have went wrong?

here is what my docker-compose.yaml looks like

```
version: '3.3'
  services:
   server:
    image: docker-image-url.com/org/server-api:v0.0.2
   ports:
     - "8888:8888"
   networks:
     - spb_net
   client:
    image: client-web:0.0.50
    ports:
      - "3000:8080"
    depends_on: 
      - server
    networks:
      - spb_net
   cypress:
    image: cypress-test:0.0.36
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - client
    networks:
      - spb_net
  networks:
   spb_net:
```

When I used curl to check the connection from the client container "curl -v http://server:8888" it's able to establish the connection.

I tried accessing the client and server container from the host and they were working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared also a network, you need to `expose` the ports of your containers, try something like this:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
  services:
    server:
      image: docker-image-url.com/org/server-api:v0.0.2
      ports:
        - "8888:8888"
      expose:
        - "8888"
      networks:
        - spb_net

    client:
      image: client-web:0.0.50
      ports:
        - "3000:8080"
      expose:
        - "8080"
      depends_on: 
        - server
      networks:
        - spb_net

    cypress:
      image: cypress-test:0.0.36
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
      expose:
        - "5000"
      depends_on:
        - client
      networks:
        - spb_net
  networks:
   spb_net:
```

Comment: thanks, I tried updating my docker-compose to this but still doesn't work.